# Hazelcast lock released while other members leaves the cluster

Tags: hazelcast

Facing a very strange scenario where lock is released unexpectedly when multiple member leaves from hazelcast cluster.

**Scenario :**

Having a cluster with 5 nodes [A, B, C, D, E] where A being the first member in the cluster and then B , C, D, E.

Node D is holding a lock.
Node E is waiting for the same which is locked by Node D.

If nodes [A, B, C] leaves the cluster in one go then lock is released by Node D where D Node is still up and running. Node D has become master due to oldest member in the cluster.

**Why the lock is released by Node D ?**

**Is it something to do with SplitBrain Condition ?**

If a single node(any of A, B, C) one by one leaves the cluster then everything works fine. Lock is still being hold by Node D and E is waiting for it to become available.

**Configuration**

```
Config config = new Config();
config.getGroupConfig().setName("group-101");
NetworkConfig networkCOnfig = config.getNetworkConfig();
networkConfig.getJoin().getTcpIoConfig().setEnabled(true);
networkConfig.getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
networkConfig.getJoin().getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
networkConfig.setPort(5701);
networkConfig.getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setMemebers(Arrays.asList("ip1","ip2"));
Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

Locks are fail-safe. If a member holds a lock and some other members go down, the cluster will keep your locks safe and available. Moreover, when a member leaves the cluster, all the locks acquired by that dead member will be removed so that those locks are immediately available for live members.

See here for details: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.1/manual/html-single/index.html#lock

Comment: Yes saw that. But in my case the member which is holding the lock is not getting down. Other member getting down.

Comment: Can you post a reproducer here, along with configs?

Comment: Added the config in question

Comment: You have a reproducer that can be shared here?

Comment: Can't post it. But just to give details using the simple lock api to get the lock. Nothing special on that.  Similarly like this : https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/index.html#lock

Comment: Is their any property/config missing which is required it to be fail-safe lock in all circumstances ?